# How does creating a new session affect initialization of variables in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, initialization

I have a very simple graph with one fully connected layer as follows:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,])
with tf.variable_scope("FC"): 
    logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(X, 1, activation_fn = tf.nn.tanh, scope='myFC', weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=10))
loss_tf = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits - y))
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
updates_tf = opt.minimize(loss_tf)
```

My goal here is to test how the seed works, hence I added a seed in the xavier initializer in the fully connected layer. I was testing this with two different methods:
The first one is the following:

```
data, labels = prepData()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
    oldLosses = []
    for epoch in range(0, 2):
        _, loss = sess.run([updates_tf, loss_tf], {X: data.T, y: labels})
        oldLosses.append(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
    newLosses = []
    for epoch in range(0, 2):
        _, loss = sess.run([updates_tf, loss_tf], {X: data.T, y: labels})
        newLosses.append(loss)
if oldLosses == newLosses:
    print("BOTH ARE SAME")
else:
    print("THEY ARE NOT THE SAME")
```

and it outputs "BOTH ARE SAME", i.e. it resets everything and reinitializes the weights, **as I expected**.
The second test I did, **with only 1 line deleted from the above code**, reinitializes the variables, but in the same session, outputs "THEY ARE NOT THE SAME":

```
data, labels = prepData()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
    oldLosses = []
    for epoch in range(0, 2):
        _, loss = sess.run([updates_tf, loss_tf], {X: data.T, y: labels})
        oldLosses.append(loss)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
    newLosses = []
    for epoch in range(0, 2):
        _, loss = sess.run([updates_tf, loss_tf], {X: data.T, y: labels})
        newLosses.append(loss)
if oldLosses == newLosses:
    print("BOTH ARE SAME")
else:
    print("THEY ARE NOT THE SAME")
```

I was wondering how creating a new session affects the initialization of variables, or is there something else I am not seeing going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally found the answer to my question on pages 7-9 of [this document](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/2017/lectures/notes_05.pdf). Basically, for this case, if you add the seed at operator level, i.e. within the constructor of the initializer as opposed to adding it on the graph level(with tf.set_random_seed), each operator keeps its own seed. Since we have one operator here, calling it multiple times without creating a new session will not change. However, if we create a new session, the operator will be recreated and the seed will be the same, hence the results will be the same in subsequent runs.